# Repositories with Laravel, saving image to DB

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have setup a repository to create a new resident.

```
 <?php namespace Crescent\Repos;

   interface ResidentRepository {
        public function create($input);
 }
```

Then in my controller I have, which uses the intervention image class to resize an image and it uploads correctly to the directory, but how can I save the name of the file to the DB using this repo?

```
 public function store()
   {

   if (Input::hasFile('photo')){

     $res = new Residents;

     $file = Input::file('photo');
     $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();

     $input = Input::all();

     $image = Image::make(Input::file('photo')->getRealPath())->resize(200, 200);
     $image->save(public_path() . '/uploads/residents/' . $input['photo']->getClientOriginalName());
     $res->photo = $name; // This doesn't work

    }
    $this->resident->create(Input::all());

    }
```

Everything else works all the data, but the image isn't storing the name just showing some temp dir/name like /tmp/phpIX7KcY

Comment: How have you implemented the interface ResidentRepository?

Comment: I've fixed it by adding the create method to the controller for now.

Answer (score 3):

I see that you have done `$res = new Residents;` and `$res->photo = $name;` but you haven't done `$res->save();` which would have saved the name to the table corresponding to `Residents`. Also since you haven't added anything else to `$res`, only the photo would be saved.

Replace the code in your controller with the following:

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    if (Input::hasFile('photo')){

       $file = Input::file('photo');
       $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();


       $image = Image::make(Input::file('photo')->getRealPath())->resize(200, 200);
       $image->save(public_path() . '/uploads/residents/' . $input['photo']->getClientOriginalName());

       $input['photo'] = $name;
   }

   $this->resident->create($input);

}
```

If in your code `$this->resident->create(Input::all());` saves all data properly except the photo, it is because by passing `Input::all()` you're saving everything exactly as it was received from the client and the filename received from the resizing operation isn't present in `Input::all()`. By assigning `Input::all()` to the variable `$input` and doing `$input['photo'] = $name;`, the location of the file on the server is stored instead of the location on the client. So, by doing `$this->resident->create($input);`, the location on the server is stored along with other data received from the client.

Comment: Great thanks for the update I'll try this out. I didnt use $res->save(); because it was saving to the DB twice because I have the Input:all() been called twice.